# Deploying Silverlight WCF service to IIS server gives error "Consider marking with DataContractAttribute"

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight application with a Silverlight-enabled WCF service.  The service passes along a small POCO class with a few string properties, and a List<> of an enum defined in the class.  Everything works fine when running using the ASP.NET development server, but when I move the service over to an IIS server (Windows 2003) I get the following error when I try to browse the .svc file:

> Type 'MyProject.Web.MyClass' cannot be
>   serialized. Consider marking it with
>   the DataContractAttribute attribute,
>   and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Even though it's working development side, I've tried adding the decorations... but so far without effect.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this difference of outcomes between development workstation and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that (1) the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is installed on the server and (2) that the website is running in ASP.Net 2.0 mode and not 1.1 mode.

The [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is an easy way to install the updated framework if it isn't already installed.

Comment: Thanks.  It was SP1 for .NET Framework 3.5 that was needed.  From the MSDN site about SP1 benefits - "WCF improvements that give developers more control over the way they access data and services Streamlined installation experience for client applications"

Comment: Not sure I agree with your comment about WPI - *every single time I have used it the installation has failed without giving a reason. This is at least 6 times

Answer (score 1):

Your data elements (POCO classes) ought to be marked as DataContracts for WCF, so that WCF knows explicitly what it'll need to serialize to send across the wire.

Contrary to the Xml Serializer, the DataContractSerializer in WCF uses an "opt-in" model - only things that you **explicitly** mark as `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` will be serialized - anything else will be ignored.

```
[DataContract]
class YourPocoClass
{
   [DataMember]
   private int _ID;

   [DataMember]
   string CustomerName { get; set; } 

   public decimal CustomerOrderAmount { get; set; } 
}
```

In this example, from `YourPocoClass`, you'll have both the `_ID` field and the `CustomerName` property be serialized into the WCF message - but the `CustomerOrderAmount` will **not** be serialized - `public` or not.

So, best practice is: explicitly mark all your complex types that you need to send around in WCF with [DataContract] (for the class) and [DataMember] (for each member to be sent across inside that class).

Marc

Comment: Why does is serialize just fine in development without decorations?

Comment: That's a "simplification" that's been introduced, but it seems to work only half of the time. Do it explicitly - it's easier and states your intent much more clearly.

Comment: +1 Marc, thank you very much for your help.  I gave the accepted answer to Bryant because he answered very specifically the cause of the problem I encountered, but I very much appreciate your advice and clarity on best practices.  Thanks!